# Git Committed Conflicts

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have been working with Git Bitbucket. I store my project on a Dropbox directory and whenever I do some work I follow this procedure:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "done some changes"
git push origin master
```

Now the majority of the time this works and I see my commit. Earlier I did this, and it said I was behind when I did a push and suggested for me to pull. so I did this and pulled a lot of conflicts. I then tried to commit again like before with the staged changes, and when I check my revisions, I see that around 30 of my files have the difference like so:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

==========

>>>>>>> 1adba6524d0294b7d77463ceff16fef8bb2a58b4
```

I don't know how the hell it got so complicated, but now I have a project that doesn't work. It treated this as part of a merge when I pushed. I never got anything to say "resolve conflicts" like I usually see in SVN.

How can I get it back to how it was without doing so manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you push the changes with the conflict lines to the repository already?  (Also, why are you even bothering with the Dropbox bit?  You've got the repo on Bitbucket already!)

Comment: Yeah I've moved it out of Dropbox, but a lot of assets are associated with the project that are not in the repo. I also would get conflicted copies from my macbook.

Comment: Right - the question I phrased before the tangent was if the code with conflicts was pushed to the tip of master.  If it was, then we're going to want to remove those.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`git mergetool`

By default, it opens `vimdiff` for flipping through and deciding what conflicting files to discard changes to, but you can install a GUI like [p4merge](http://www.andymcintosh.com/?p=33) instead and use it like this:

`git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

  ** code of your HEAD at here **

==========

  ** code of which have conflict commit in here **

>>>>>>> 1adba6524d0294b7d77463ceff16fef8bb2a58b4(this is the commit version)
```

you should fix conflict and remove the tips in your code,then commit it again.

when you fix you code, you can execute

```
git add .
git commit -m 'fix conflict'
git push
```

again.

I think the GUI tool can help you [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)